# Looking for better query without using NOT EXISTS in mysql

Tags: mysql, not-exists

My application has some shelves which go through an audit regularly. I have to find out shelves which are not yet added in the current audit.
The schema looks like the following

```
shelf : [id,code,status,...]
shelf_audit: [id,sub_audit_id,shelf_id,...]
sub_audit : [id,audit_id,status,..]
audit : [id,status]
```

There are multiple sub_audit in a particular audit and shelf_audit represents the shelves added to sub_audit.
I can get the shelves not added to current audit using the following query

```
select distinct s.code
from shelf s
where not exists
(
    select distinct sa.shelf_id
    from shelf_audit sa
    join sub_audit scc
        on (sa.sub_audit_id = scc.id
    and scc.audit_id = @currentAuditId)   
    where sa.shelf_id = s.id
) and s.status='ACTIVE' ;
```

I want to do it without using **NOT EXISTS** as it is giving very poor performance in mysql database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a LEFT Join between shelf and shelf audit where shelf audit .shelf_Id is null?  basically return all records from shelf where no corresponding record exists in shelf audit.

Comment: i tried that too, but that gives no rows as the join matches rows in shelf_audit from previous audits

Comment: this is not relevant but do you think the following join is really necessary? `(scc.sub_audit_id=aa.id and aa.id=@currentAuditId)` don't you already have the `currentAuditId` in `scc.sub_audit_id`?

Comment: @OzgurBar changed that part

Answer (score 0):

without full consideration of the sub query... something simple like this?

```
Select distinct code
from shelf S
left join  (select distinct sa.shelf_id
    from shelf_audit sa
    join sub_audit scc
        on sa.sub_audit_id = scc.id
    join audit aa
        on (scc.sub_audit_id = aa.id and aa.id = @currentAuditId)   
    where sa.shelf_id = s.id) B
 on S.Id = B.Shelf_ID
where s.status = 'ACTIVE'
  and B.Shelf_ID is null
```

Comment: where sa.shelf_id = s.id is not required here

Answer (score 0):

Temp table can be used as below to improve performance

```
select distinct sa.shelf_id
into #temp
from shelf_audit sa
join sub_audit scc
    on (sa.sub_audit_id = scc.id
and scc.audit_id = @currentAuditId)   

select distinct code from shelf s where status='ACTIVE' and
not exists (select top 1 * from #temp where shelf_id = s.id)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That did help, though not to the extent i wanted. Thanks

Comment: You could put the required subquery in a temp table and use where id not in. It would also help to improve performance.

Comment: NOT IN will not result in any row if the sub query returns null (e.g very first time when there is no audit yet)

Comment: Where not exists can be used with temp table as well

Comment: NOT IN is quite better that NOT EXISTS in mysql and i am using it with HQL (HIbernate) and don't think creating a temporary table each time i query would be a great idea.